# When mixed partial derivatives do not exist but are equal to 0

Tags: real-analysis

Good evening everybody.

The following question came to my mind while reading an old American Math. Monthly paper entitled "Double integrals as initial value problems".

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be a function. Assume that $f$ has the following property: for any $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$, it holds that
$$\frac{f(x+h,y+h)-f(x+h,y)-f(x,y+h)+f(x,y)}{h^2}\to 0\qquad\hbox{as $h\to 0$}\tag{$*$} $$
Does it follow that $f$ has the form $f(x,y)=u(x)+v(y)$, where $u$ and $v$ are $1$-variable functions?

Note that the answer is "Yes" if $f$ is known to be twice differentiable, since in this cas $(*)$ means that $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}\equiv 0$. The point is that no regularity assumption is *a priori* made on $f$.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Your title does not really make sense...

Comment: Hopefully, the question does...

Comment: The  question does already. But something that doesn't exist cannot be zero because zero exists.

Comment: What about taking this just as a joke (possibly not a good one)?

Comment: Etienne It wasn't a joke. I like your question (upvoted it), but your title still is nonsense.

Comment: Thanks for upvoting. Actually, I had no idea for a title, so I decided to put an absurd one. This is what I meant in my previous comment : consider the title as a joke.

Comment: LoL, now I see. Sorry!